# All upper and lowercase permutations of a string

Tags: python, combinatorics

A couple of questions:

1. Is the algorithm wasting CPU time or memory unnecessarily?
2. If there is something in the code that is not idiomatic Python, how to improve on that?

```
def permute_first( c ):
    retval = []
    retval.append( c.upper() )
    retval.append( c.lower() )
    return retval

def permute( str ):
    leads = permute_first( str[0] )
    remain = str[1:]
    if not remain:
        return leads
    permutations = permute( remain )
    new_permutations = []
    for perm in permutations :
        for lead in leads:
            new_permutations.append( lead + perm )  
    return new_permutations

og = "Question"
print permute( og )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The base case in your recursion is incorrect: it should be an empty string, not a one-character string.

Extraneous whitespace inside parentheses is explicitly un-Pythonic, by [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#pet-peeves).

There is usually a better way to do this pattern, which you used twice:

> ```
> some_list = []
> some_list.append(element)
> some_list.append(more_stuff)
> return some_list
> ```

There is often a one-liner to define the entire list at once, possibly involving a list comprehension.  Or, if it's a "long" list, you may want to stream the results as a generator, as I've done below.

```
def capitalization_permutations(s):
    """Generates the different ways of capitalizing the letters in
    the string s.

    >>> list(capitalization_permutations('abc'))
    ['ABC', 'aBC', 'AbC', 'abC', 'ABc', 'aBc', 'Abc', 'abc']
    >>> list(capitalization_permutations(''))
    ['']
    >>> list(capitalization_permutations('X*Y'))
    ['X*Y', 'x*Y', 'X*y', 'x*y']
    """
    if s == '':
        yield ''
        return
    for rest in capitalization_permutations(s[1:]):
        yield s[0].upper() + rest
        if s[0].upper() != s[0].lower():
            yield s[0].lower() + rest
```

Answer (score 4):

#### 1. Review

1. "Permutations" is not the right word for what this code does. The permutations of a sequence are the different ways the items can be ordered: for example, the permutations of ABC are ABC, ACB, BAC, BCA, CAB and CBA. These can be computed using the built-in [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

   ```
   >>> from itertools import permutations
   >>> list(map(''.join, permutations('ABC')))
   ['ABC', 'ACB', 'BAC', 'BCA', 'CAB', 'CBA']
   ```

   What you have here are the different ways to capitalize the letters in a word, so the name ought to be something like `capitalizations`.
2. There are no docstrings. What do these functions do and how to I call them?
3. The [Python style guide (PEP8)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends:

   > Avoid extraneous whitespace … immediately inside parentheses, brackets or braces.
4. The body of `permute_first` could be written more simply:

   ```
   return [c.upper(), c.lower()]
   ```

   In fact this is so simple that there's no real need for this to be a separate function at all.
5. If `str` contains non-letters then we get duplicates in the output:

   ```
   >>> permute('<>')
   ['<>', '<>', '<>', '<>']
   ```

   Use `sorted(set((c.upper(), c.lower())))` to de-duplicate the output.
6. If `str` is the empty string, `permute` raises `IndexError`. It should return a list containing the empty string.

#### 2. Revised code

This is a one-liner using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

def capitalizations(s):
    """Return a list of the different ways of capitalizing the letters in
    the string s.

    >>> capitalizations('abc')
    ['ABC', 'ABc', 'AbC', 'Abc', 'aBC', 'aBc', 'abC', 'abc']
    >>> capitalizations('')
    ['']
    >>> capitalizations('X*Y')
    ['X*Y', 'X*y', 'x*Y', 'x*y']

    """
    return list(map(''.join, product(*(sorted(set((c.upper(), c.lower())))
                                       for c in s))))
```

Comment: Just an additional note about permutations: it would be good to add that "permutation" can refer to index-based permutations (*e.g.* `itertools.permutations`) as well as to value-based permutations (*e.g.* `std::next_permutation`) which are somehow different beasts under a same name.

Comment: Good point on naming, I'll change it to something more suitable. I made permute_first a function since I experimented with other substitions as well, like i and l to 1, but simplified it for the sake of this submission. I wrote this because I want to list all possible written forms of any base word irregardless of capitalization, and it's easy to expand that function to cover l33t speak as well.